# How to access values inside a tuple which is inside nested dictionary

Tags: python

```
h={'PC3': [
      '03:03:03:03:03:03', '192.168.0.3', '200', {
        '192.168.0.1': ('01:01:01:01:01:01', 1390618305.477), 
        '192.168.0.4': ('04:04:04:04:04:04', 1390618305.481), 
        '192.168.0.5': ('05:05:05:05:05:05', 1390618305.480)
      }
   ], 
   'PC1': [
     '01:01:01:01:01:05', '192.168.0.1', '200', {}
   ]
}
```

My requirement is that user enters input e.g. PC3 or PC1(there can be many PCs this is just to give idea). For example, I enter PC3

Now I need to look inside nested dictionary associated with that PC(e.g.PC3 in this case). For every key inside its dictionary I need to check whether 2nd value of tuple is less than 1390618305.478, if true  I would delete that entry(key) e.g. it should delete '192.168.0.1' and print nothing.

else
I want to print 1st value of tuple and key associated e.g. 04:04:04:04:04:04 and 192.168.0.4 in the follwing format
04:04:04:04:04:04   192.168.0.4

For every entry inside nested dictionary of a particular PC i would do that and if condition is false i would print that. Otherwise if condition is true i would remove that. Every entry that I print should be on new line.e.g

```
04:04:04:04:04:04   192.168.0.4
05:05:05:05:05:05   192.168.0.5
```

and in this case 192.168.0.1 would get deleted.

Comment: This is all what you would like to do. What have you tried so far??

Comment: Yes, all. I tried to do but couldn't come with such conditions.

Comment: Always post your code and ask for help with it.

Comment: To get you started: `h['PC3'][1]` is `'192.168.0.3'`, and `h['PC3'][3]['192.168.0.1']` is `('01:01:01:01:01:01', 1390618305.477)`. Try figuring out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for item in h['PC3']:
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for key in item.keys():
            if item[key][1] < 1390618305.478:
                item.pop(key, None)
            else:
                print item[key][0], key
```

The above code gives following result:

```
04:04:04:04:04:04 192.168.0.4
05:05:05:05:05:05 192.168.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ip, (mac, t) in h['PC3'][3].items():
    if not t < 1390618305.478: print mac, ip
```

This produces:

```
04:04:04:04:04:04 192.168.0.4
05:05:05:05:05:05 192.168.0.5
```

To also delete the other keys:

```
from copy import deepcopy
h={ 'PC3': ['03:03:03:03:03:03', '192.168.0.3', '200', {'192.168.0.1': ('01:01:01:01:01:01', 1390618305.477), '192.168.0.4': ('04:04:04:04:04:04', 1390618305.481), '192.168.0.5': ('05:05:05:05:05:05', 1390618305.480)}], 'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:05', '192.168.0.1', '200', {}]}

hcopy = deepcopy(h)
for ip, (mac, t) in h['PC3'][3].items():
    if t < 1390618305.478:
         del hcopy['PC3'][3][ip]
    else:
        print mac, ip
h = hcopy
```

The above deletes the unwanted items from a copy of h.  This is done because deleting items from something that we are, at the same time, iterating over can lead to some very strange bugs.

Comment: I also want to delete entries that have <1390618305.478. I cannot see that case here